# No longer access to the library ObjService from James Ferreira (MTeYmpfWgqPbiBkVHnpgnM9kh30YExdAc)

Tags: google-apps-script, shared-libraries

For years I have been using a container-bound script to extract data from a Google Spreadsheet, and that script relies heavily on the ObjService library from James Ferreira (Project Key: MTeYmpfWgqPbiBkVHnpgnM9kh30YExdAc), specifically the ObjApp.rangeToObjects() function.

Recently my custom menu no longer appears on the Spreadsheet because that library is Not Found.
Removing the library from the resources permits my custom menu to be accessible again, but I am no longer able to add the library ObjService back to my project, and therefore my script no longer works.

I have disabled the new Apps Script runtime powered by Chrome V8 and still cannot reload the library, both from the Legacy or New Editor.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are encountering this behavior is mainly because the `Script ID` you are trying to use is not a correct one or you no longer have the permissions necessary in order to be able to use this library.

[image: insert library]

I suggest you double-check the `Script ID` you are using and **check if this library is still available for use.**

Comment: I am sure it is the correct ID for the library, I have been accessing it and using it for years with that ID. Also, it is a public library (see the Google Apps Script book from James Ferreira), it does not have permission restrictions.

Comment: The permissions might have changed in the meantime; same goes with the `Script ID`. I think the best solution in this situation is to seek support on this page’s library.

Answer (score -1):

After searching for another library to use, I found the code for the ObjService library I was trying to keep access to, here:
https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/gs-objects/source
and I have directly included it into my project.
The messy headers with quirky characters are back to no longer being an issue and everything is working again. Yeah!